# How to scrape all the data from the table which reveals on clicking button?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to scrape the website : https://gmatclub.com/forum/decision-tracker.html I need to get the decision tracker table - real time updates. The code below **gives me the data that is present in the current page**.

As you scroll down, there is a 'show more' button, which makes old entries display. What will be the way to get all the data from the table. (all the 5500+ entries)

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

with requests.Session() as connection:
    connection.headers.update(
        {
            "referer": "https://gmatclub.com/forum/decision-tracker.html",
            "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.86 YaBrowser/21.3.0.740 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36",
        }
    )
    _ = connection.get("https://gmatclub.com/forum/decision-tracker.html")
    endpoint = connection.get("https://gmatclub.com/api/schools/v1/forum/app-tracker-latest-updates?limit=50&year=all").json()
    for item in endpoint["statistics"]:
        print(item)

#df = pd.DataFrame(endpoint["statistics"])
#print(df.head())
#df.to_csv("your_table_data.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and easier solution to your problem is to define the highest limit (you want to get data up to) within params. I parsed the `id` only to let you know it works. You can stick with your dataframe approach.

```
import requests

link = 'https://gmatclub.com/api/schools/v1/forum/app-tracker-latest-updates'
params = {
    'limit': 500,
    'offset': 0,
    'year': 'all'
}

with requests.Session() as con:
    con.headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.86 YaBrowser/21.3.0.740 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
    con.get("https://gmatclub.com/forum/decision-tracker.html")
    while True:
        endpoint = con.get(link,params=params).json()
        if not endpoint["statistics"]:break
        for item in endpoint["statistics"]:
            print(item['id'])

        params['offset']+=499
```

Comment: it is not giving me more than 500 entries. and its the same all over again. and if i increase the limit, nothing would change

Comment: Woah, I think this works perfectly. Have a follow up question - You think I could ask here?

Comment: Sure, you can. I'll be back couple of hours from now. Btw, the site sometimes ignores requests, so you might want to have a `try/except` clause in place. However, that is a different question.

Comment: alright!!
Yes, I observed that. Thank you so much!

Comment: I am able to get almost all the data, and have successfuly got it into a csv file. Just wondering: How do the parameters work, cause each time we hit show more 'offset' increases by 100.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. According to dev tools, this is what we get. However, we can find something otherwise playing around with those offset keys and that is what I found out. Thanks.

Comment: I am not able to connect anymore. getting :
```ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))```